# PySpark - JSON to RDD/coalesce

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

Based on the suggestion to [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026441/pyspark-rdd-to-json/51026723), I was able to transform my RDD into a JSON in the format I want. In order to save this to HDFS, I'd like to convert this back to an RDD and use `coalesce` to save it into 10 partition files.

What I'm doing so far:

- convert to an RDD using `my_rdd = sc.parallelize([my_json])`
- coalesce and save using `my_rddcoalesce(10).saveAsTextFile`

In my tests, this executes successfully but only one of the 10 partition files has data. On further checks, it looks like the entire json file is loaded into the RDD as a single record, as opposed to one record per json element, resulting in the `coalesce` function being unable to split the data properly.

I tried issuing `hadoop fs -text <saved_file_partition> |head -n 1` and the entire JSON was spat out, as opposed to only the first record.

How can I convert my JSON object to an RDD properly?

Comment: The default hdfs block size (a property passed to spark) is 128Mb... Do you have that much JSON or more?

Comment: I would think so - the initial RDD has a little over 20 million rows. Put another way - when I issue `hadoop fs -text <saved_file_partition>|wc -l` it returns 1, showing that the entire JSON is encoded into one record

Comment: Sounds like you have a single JSON Array, not one JSON object per line. From the previous question, you must instead output individual objects. (ip, category, score) (newline) (ip, category, score), (newline), etc. Each line being it's own individual JSON record just like the CSV output

Answer (score 0):

Since you define `RDD` like

```
sc.parallelize([my_json])
```

it will have only one record and single records are never split between partitions. Therefore it doesn't matter how many partitions you use - there can be only one non-empty partition in your dataset.

Comment: So how would I convert my JSON object into an RDD so that it can be partitioned?